# How do I make a form in Access become a Pop-up Window?

Tags: ms-access, popup, ms-access-2010

I am looking to make the forms I have in Access pop-up forms. I have a picture of what I want (the picture is from a different file)

[image]

and this is what I have

[image]

As far as I can tell, there is no difference in the Macros, the settings, and the VBA code between the two files. How do I make my forms pop out like the one pictured?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried `DoCmd.OpenForm "YouFormName", , , , , acDialog` ?

---

If you want to permanently define your form as a pop-up just go to the form's

```
Property Sheet -> "Other" Tab > Set "Pop Up" to "Yes"
```

Comment: Yes, I have that piece of code in my VBA macro already, but it still only opens the form, it doesn't make it a separate window.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm pretty unfamiliar with Access, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the default window view of the database.

Go to File ¬ Options and select the "Current Database"  option on the left side.

In that option list there is a section under Application Options that says "Document Window Options"
Select Overlapping Windows instead of Tabbed Documents.

Comment: To note: if you have the "Pop Up" property set to "Yes", the database windows can be set to either tabbed or overlapping

Answer (score 0):

2016 Microsoft Access (as of 2020)

**Normal Navigation**

Method 1: **File** > **Options** (**Access Option** Window Pop-up) > *Left Column Toolbar*: **Current database navigation** > Document Window Options > Select **Overlapping Windows**

---

**Alt Key Shortcuts**

Fast Method 2: Alt + F > Alt+ T > Press Alt + O